# History.pushState only working on second back button with backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browser-history, pushstate, html5-history

I am trying to get `back` and `forward` buttons working within a backbone single page application with `history.pushState` and `router.navigate`.

I had everything working until I realised that on apple products (MAC, iPhone, iPad) the `popstate` event is fired on page load! Nightmare!

So I have been playing around trying to get everything working, I have prevented `popstate` from firing on page load and managed to get the `back` and `forward` buttons to work, but unfortunately they don't work on the first click. I have figured out why but I don't know how to fix it!

Here is some code:

```
window.onpopstate = function (event) {
    Backbone.trigger('popstate', event);
};
```

The above code is used to trigger my backbone function when the `popstate` event fires.

```
ContainerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'body',
    events: {
        ...
    },
    initialize: function() {        
        ...
        ...
        this.listenTo(Backbone, 'popstate', this.onPopState);
    },
    onPopState: function(event) {
        app.popStateTriggered = true;
        if (event.state && _.keys(event.state).length > 0) {
            var pathName = window.location.pathname;
            var pageName = "index.php";
            if(pathName.indexOf(".php") > -1) {
                var pageName = pathName.substring(pathName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, pathName.lastIndexOf('php') + 3);
            }
            $('.navigation-item[href="'+pageName+'"]').eq(0).click();
        }
    },
    ...
```

The above code listens to the trigger of `popsate` and runs the `onPopState` function. The `onPopState` function reads to see if an `event.stat`e has been passed, this is how I prevent the code from running on page load, if there is a `event.status` then the code runs and loads the requested view.

```
window.history.pushState({ customState: pageUrl }, pageName, pageUrl);
```

The above is my `pushState` function.

Where my problem stands is that when I press the back button for the first time `event.stats = undefined` (BAD) and then on the second hit of the back button `event.status = object{ customState: "index.php" }` (GOOD). But why does this only work the second time, I cannot work it out, its driving me crazy!

If anyone could help that would be awesome!

**EDIT**

Here is my router:

```
var app = app || {};

(function($) {

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'instantiateHome',
            'index.php': 'instantiateHome',
            'our-approach.php': 'instantiateOurApproach',
            'our-work.php': 'instantiateOurWork',
            'people.php': 'instantiatePeople',
            'social.php': 'instantiateSocial',
            'contact-us.php': 'instantiateContactUs',
            "*notFound" : 'notFound'
        },
        instantiateHome: function() {
            if (app.ajaxActive) {... // instantiateView()}
        },
        instantiateOurApproach: function() {
            ... // instantiateView()
        },
        instantiateOurWork: function() {
            ... // instantiateView()
        },
        instantiatePeople: function() {
            ... // instantiateView()
        },
        instantiateSocial: function() {
            ... // instantiateView()
        },
        instantiateContactUs: function() {
            ... // instantiateView()
        },
        notFound: function() {
            ... // instantiateView()
        }
    });

    app.router = new Router();

    var location_pathname = window.location.pathname;
    var site_url = location_pathname.replace(location_pathname.split("/").pop(),"");
    var urlArray = location_pathname.split("/");
    var pageUrl = urlArray[urlArray.length-1];
    if (Modernizr.history) {
        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: site_url});
    } else {
        Backbone.history.start({hashChange: false, root: site_url});
    }

    app.router.navigate(pageUrl, {trigger: true});

    history.replaceState({ customState: true });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can I see where your routes are defined?

Comment: @KenWheeler I have updated it for you.

Comment: Hey, did you ever manage to figure this out? It seems to be happening for me (using vanilla JS, no frameworks) sometimes...